# How to commit and push MySQL Workbench code to GitHub?

Tags: mysql, github

I can't find the information, how to upload MySQL code to GitHub repository from MySQL Workbench?

Could you help me somebody?
I mean code like this from MySQL Workbench:

[image: MySQL Workbench]

Answer (score 0):

If [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/) does not provide a native Git integration, your best bet is to switch back to console/command-line and:

- create a repository locally
- create a remote empty repository on GitHub
- add, commit and push your local file in the new repository.

Comment: I connected MySQL to Visual Studio Code and there is a Terminal like in Pycharm, where I can write details to commit and push to GitHub, but I can't find a way to commit and push MySQL file/codes from VSC to GitHub. Have you idea about that?

Comment: @AndrejusJaroslavcevas Add GitLens (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#remotes-view) and you can push with it.